# Construct predicate in subquery from templates

Tags: ios, objective-c, subquery, nspredicate, predicate

I have the need to construct some fairly complex predicates in my app based on the user's selection of filter criteria. The constructed predicate is then used to fetch data from the app's Core Data database.

Part of the filter predicate involves a subquery expression with some more varying and complex predicates that construct the subquery's predicate. I want to optimize my code and avoid parsing strings every time the filter predicate is created. So I have been using predicate templates and `predicateWithSubstitutionVariables:` as well as `NSCompoundPredicate` to construct the predicates from the various filter predicate components.

My problem is how to construct the final predicate with the subquery expression and subquery predicate constructed from predicate templates.

I tried using a predicate template for the subquery itself, but it was unable to parse the format string:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(routes, $route, $ROUTE_PREDICATE).@count > 0"];
```

`$ROUTE_PREDICATE` in this instance is the complex predicate I'm constructing from other predicate templates which themselves use `$route` to evaluate expressions from the route's attributes.

I then tried to construct the predicate with the subquery predicate as an argument in the formatting method and it was again unable to parse the format string:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(routes, $route, %@).@count > 0", routePredicate];
```

`routePredicate` is again the complex predicate constructed from other predicate templates.

Now I am working on constructing the predicate using the `expressionForSubquery:usingIteratorVariable:predicate:` method of `NSExpression`. This is what I have so far:

```
[NSExpression expressionForSubquery:[NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"routes"] usingIteratorVariable:@"route" predicate:routePredicate];
```

Which should give me the subquery expression portion. Then I have an `NSComparisonPredicate` to do the comparison of > 0.

```
[NSComparisonPredicate predicateWithLeftExpression:expression rightExpression:[NSExpression expressionForConstantValue:@0] modifier:NSDirectPredicateModifier type:NSGreaterThanPredicateOperatorType options:0];
```

I'm stuck on how to evaluate the subquery expression with `.count` to create the `expression` variable portion of the final `NSComparisonPredicate`. I'm thinking it will involve another expression `[NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"count"]`, but I'm not sure how to evaluate this with the subquery expression.

That is if this will even get me to where I'm trying to be, constructing the final predicate from the subquery predicate constructed from predicate templates and substitution variables. Am I on the right track? Is there a better way to go about this?

**EDIT:**
I tried this:

```
[NSComparisonPredicate predicateWithLeftExpression:[NSExpression expressionWithFormat:@"%@.@count", expression] rightExpression:[NSExpression expressionForConstantValue:@0] modifier:NSDirectPredicateModifier type:NSGreaterThanPredicateOperatorType options:0];
```

Where `expression` is the subquery expression above. The code runs like this. Now to see if it does what I want it too...

**EDIT 2:**
The query does function as expected with that implementation. The only unnecessary string parsing is in `[NSExpression expressionWithFormat:@"%@.@count", expression]`. So if anyone knows how to do this without the format string method, please let me know.